# Looks like a font is missing

Tags: nautilus, fonts, menu

Nautilus has become like this:

[image: nautilus output]

Global menus now have this ugly font.

Any idea why? It looks like an update killed it.

[image: nautilus output]
[image: nautilus output]
[image: nautilus output]
[image: font settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily mean that something is missing. There might be a number of causes for this. There might be a newly installed font which got higher priority for some reason, a setting might have been changed etc.

To fix this, try installing [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/). Then run it, go to Tweaks > Fonts. Here's how my settings look like, and I do believe they're default:

[image: Ubuntu Default Fonts]

By the way, 'ugly' is pretty subjective. I actually like the font on your screenshot :)

Comment: Thanks. But something is obviously wrong. Font isn't consistent across apps, launcher and menus. I also have double menu in Nautilus. Please see my updated screens.

Comment: Have you tried to do what I wrote in my answer? Also, can you please post a screenshot of the Ubuntu Tweak > Tweaks > Fonts window?

Comment: Updated, don't know what to change. Хвала земљаче :)

Comment: Што не причаш да смо наши :) I'm not sure what could be the problem. Your settings seem to be alright. I'll have to look around and I'll let you know.

Comment: Извини друже, нисам успео да провалим у чему је проблем овде. Sorry, I wasn't able to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: Звучи невероватно, али проблем је нестао сам од себе. For some reason, problem is gone aftere few restarts.

Comment: Ето, бар сам помогао :) Perhaps ownership for some fonts got messed up, and then an update fixed it, or something similar.

Comment: Just to make it a bit more clear (cause I'm having a very similiar issue) what's your Ubuntu version, are you using any X related PPAs, what graphic drivers do you use? I'm running clean 12.10 here with fglrx driver and Xorg-edgers PPA enabled.